# Play framework and akka to realtime socket update

Tags: playframework, websocket, akka, playframework-2.3

I'm new in play framework, I've already created an application to manage posts and comments with ease. Now as a proof of concept I want to implement a websocket to push real-time comments(add,update,and delete) in the Page.

My idea is to send a  update Message inside the rest action in my controller but, i can't figure out what will be the best way (akka?)

EDIT.
 At the moment I'll go with Akka but no I've got no clue how to setup a basic POC.

I've change my Application.java with:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;
import java.util.*;

import akka.MyWebSocketActor;
import play.libs.F.*;
import play.mvc.WebSocket;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Socket and Actors definition 
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static WebSocket<String> socket() {
        return WebSocket.withActor(MyWebSocketActor::props);
    }
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Socket and Actors definition 
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

And I've wrote a simple MyWebSocketActor.java as:

```
package akka;

import akka.actor.*;


public class MyWebSocketActor extends UntypedActor {

    public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
        return Props.create(MyWebSocketActor.class, out);
    }

    private final ActorRef out;

    public MyWebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            out.tell("I received your message: " + message, self());
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I've got a compilation error:

```
! @6ipf58l8c - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: cannot find symbol]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(PlayReloader.scala:298) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:298) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:296) ~[na:na]
    at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1.reload(PlayReloader.scala:296) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:102) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
```

That seems to be related to:

```
    return WebSocket.withActor(MyWebSocketActor::props);
                    ^
```

In the Application.java file. 
What I'm missing?

Comment: http://ticofab.io/simple-play-websocket-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can use akka actors to impement websocket for real-time updates.

[Play Web Sockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets-advanced)

Apart from that there is one chat template provided by typesafe. You can get the idea from it:

[Chat Template](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/matthiasn-sse-chat-template)